# Reverse Bootstrap Modal Options if on a Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, browser-detection

So I am using twitter bootstrap for one of my latest projects... My client uses a Mac computer and when I showed him the demo, he said it would be cool if the buttons could flow with the operating system.

I was curious if anyone knew how to detect an operating system using JavaScript and move the buttons on the in the model to the left instead of the right. Also I would like to be able to move the close button to the left as well.

I remember seeing a theme that does this, but for the life of me can not find it.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I can't think of any significant website or web application that tries to look like the local operating system.

Comment: I have probably only seen a few. Its a very rare thing for a web app to do. But you have to admit, it is kinda of a cool feature to include.

Comment: I personally don't agree; normal web users don't expect it.

Comment: Not disagreeing. I think it will be unexpected... But its just a cool small almost pointless feature that My Client... and well if I keep using bootstrap after this, and I will be using. Just because it inst expected doesn't mean you shouldn't try it... How much fun can that be?

Comment: It screams bad user experience. The expected in most circumstances is preferential. Please don't.

Comment: You are right, the buttons dont appear to be position in a different spot from a windows alert or mac alert... But the close button is. So I might just move the close button to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any plugins that would do exactly what you want, but you can [detect](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/operatin.htm) the OS using `navigator.appversion`

```
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
```

You could then branch your code (maybe even using just CSS) based on the OS.

Comment: What would be the value for *nix (such as Ubuntu)?

Comment: Perfect... Though I am probably going to default to Windows and add a class if you use a Mac

Comment: @JeromyFrench I've updated my answer with the full excerpt from the site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `User-agent` to know the operating system.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

In javascript, you can access the user agent like this :

```
navigator.userAgent;
```

Comment: The user agent can be easily changed by the user, yes. But if you only use the user-agent to make some graphicals changes, i think it's ok.

Comment: Well that is fine, if you spoof the user-agent, well than you wont get the cool coded buttons. haha.

So using the user agent detect if mac add classes to reposition buttons, else, default classes.